# How to set attributes in NSManagedObject by selecting it from a dictionary inside an array, based on another attribute in that dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, restkit, restkit-0.20

JSONs returned by my server have a field called "files" with an array of files (which might be empty sometimes). It looks like this:

```
"files": [
            {
                "modified_date": "2014-09-16T10:45:16.213144+00:00",
                "url": "www.example.com",
                "text": "", 
                "file_type": "type2", 
                "fields": [], 
                "id": 2
            }, 
            {
                "modified_date": "2014-09-17T07:26:36.640975+00:00",
                "url": "www.example.com",
                "text": "", 
                "system": "ios", 
                "file_type": "type1",
                "subtype": "subtype1", 
                "id": 1
            }
        ],
```

In my object stored in Core Data I need to save url and modified_date from file with type2 if there is one in the array. I also have to save url and modified_date from any dictionary with type1 and where "system" == "ios" (there are 2 possible subtypes, I have fields in core data for both of them).

Is it possible to make RestKit read key/value pairs from selected dictionaries in subarray like this? If yes, how can I do it?

If all else fails, I was thinking about making another class and putting objects from "files" array into instances of that class. Then after RestKit is finished, I'd move the data I need from the "files" objects into corresponding "main" objects. But I really don't want to do it this way, so I'd appreciate help with doing it in a "simple" way as described above.

Comment: Yes, RestKit can do it, give it a try.

Comment: But how can I do it with RestKit?

Comment: You'll need to read the docs on github and give something a try, at the moment your question is too broad.

Comment: I'm reading them for the last few days and haven't found anything really helpful in my case. RKDynamicMapping was close, but it requires creating another class for files. I'm not sure how this question is too broad though? Should deleting the last paragraph help?

Comment: You will need a normal mapping, not dynamic, and you will need KVC validation (to throw out the bits you map but don't want).